# Can i save one column with many values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add many value in same column,i tried like this

```
$strsaveImage="insert into  image(Image_Id,Image_Name,Image_Detail  ,Image_Date)";
    $strsaveImage=$strsaveImage."values('$Profile_id','$target_path',$Mouths && $Bodies,'$date')";
    $objsaveImage=  mysql_query($strsaveImage) or die ("Error Query [" . $strsaveImage . "]");
```

and input is like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Bodies" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Mouths" >
```

I want to add values like bodies and mouths to image detail column.
Which method should i use,i tried operator but failed.Please help me out this.Thank you :)

Comment: you could change it into a CSV ( comma separated value ) but that will severely limit searching, usually it's best to create another table ( or 2 ) if there is a one to many relationship.

Comment: anyway what is this bit `$Mouths && $Bodies` probably your error.

Comment: there is no error,it just only save value "1",what ever i input in these field.@ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: because you are doing a comparison operation such as `if( $Mouths && $Bodies )` this will have the same effective output.  If one of these was 0, '', false or Null, it would give you a 0

Comment: you can do like `$Mouths . $Bodies` concatenation, but you have to understand you are throwing away information. such as what field they came from, so you will have trouble building an editor, searching or separating the data later.   it's best to add another field for it.

Comment: its save in mysql like 99.88 if i input 99 and another filed 88.@ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: I think should i use if ,else or switch case or loop? @ArtisiticPhoenix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your inputs are safe.
2. Make an array of the data you want saved in your column.
3. `serialize()` your array.
4. On retrieval, `unseralize()` your array.

   ```
   $imageDetail = serialize(array('Mouths' => $Mouths, 'Bodies' => $Bodies));    
   $strsaveImage="insert into  image(Image_Id,Image_Name,Image_Detail ,Image_Date)";
   $strsaveImage=$strsaveImage."values('$Profile_id','$target_path',$imageDetail,'$date')";
   $objsaveImage=  mysql_query($strsaveImage) or die ("Error Query [" . $strsaveImage . "]");
   ```

Then, when accessing the data,

```
$imageDetail = unserialize($queryData['Image_Detail']);
// Results in:
array(
     'Mouths' => 'ValueOfMouths',
     'Bodies' => 'ValueOfBodies',
)
```